# What do we mean by XPG6

Tags: limit

What do we mean by XPG6 in limits.h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPG was the [X/Open Portability Guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_Portability_Guide), a pre-POSIX consortium to promote interoperability between different UNIX vendors. XPG6 is "X/Open Portability Guide, Issue 6".